# Python formatting string escape

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, escaping

i'm trying for create a query with formatting in python, I can't figure out how i can string escape the binary input for data. It returns something like this:

> INSERT INTO `python`.`UDP` (`Packet`, `Destination`, `Source`, `Protocol`, `Version`, `Header_Length`, `TTL`, `Protoco                         l_UDP`, `Target`, `Source_Port`, `Destination_Port`, `Length`) VALUES (NULL, '00:0C:29:B2:14:0C', '192.168.178.50', '8                         ', '4', '20', '128', '17', '192.168.178.24', '52371', '8888', '29227', 'b'Data\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00                         \x00\x00\x00\x00'');)

how can you properly escape the binary string value with formatting in python?

```
def setopUDP(destination, source, protocol, version, header_length, ttl, protocolEGP, target, source_port, destination_port, length, data):
query = ("INSERT INTO `python`.`UDP` (`Packet`, `Destination`, `Source`, `Protocol`, "
         "`Version`, `Header_Length`, `TTL`, `Protocol_UDP`, `Target`, `Source_Port`, "
         "`Destination_Port`, `Length`) VALUES (NULL, '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}');)"
         .format(destination, source, protocol, version, header_length, ttl, protocolEGP, target, source_port, destination_port, length, data))


setopCON(query)
```

Comment: What database adapter are you using this with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use formatting for SQL queries. Use SQL parameters *instead*.

Your database adapter then takes care of the escaping *for you*, provided it can handle binary data.

How exactly you format SQL parameters depends on the database used; sqlite3 uses `?` placeholder:

```
query = ("INSERT INTO `python`.`UDP` (`Packet`, `Destination`, `Source`, `Protocol`, "
         "`Version`, `Header_Length`, `TTL`, `Protocol_UDP`, `Target`, `Source_Port`, "
         "`Destination_Port`, `Length`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?))")
```

and you'd pass in the list of values as the second argument to the `cursor.execute()` method:

```
cursor.execute(query,
    (destination, source, protocol, version, header_length, ttl, protocolEGP, target, source_port, destination_port, length, data))
```

You'll need to verify in your database adapter documentation what [style of SQL parameters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) are supported (one or more of `?`, `%s`, `:1`, `:name` or `%(name)s`) and how it handles binary values.

If binary values are not handled at all, you'd need to decode that binary value to a unicode value instead; use base64 encoding perhaps, or decode from Latin-1 to get a one-on-one translation into Unicode codepoints.

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone searched this topic and got led to here

This is how you do escape for "format":

```
>>> "{{}}{}".format(10)
'{}10'
```

so, `{{}}` is escaped and reduced to `{}`